# Bottom page Privacy banner is jumping underneath page bottom on Android

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, banner

Can i ask what the issue is why my div with bottom:0; is jumping to what looks like bottom:-5; on Android devices.  See image below:

**Banner issue:**

[image]

```
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color:#0c4105;
  color: white;
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
   width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .alert {
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0.11111px;
}
}

.conbtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.conbtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed  by adding minimum and maximum scales in the viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```